# What is the Euler Lagrange condition for SDEs?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-calculus, geodesic, stochastic-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

Does the Euler Lagrange condition...

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$$

...have a meaningful extension to Stochastic Differential Equations?

Comment: Old question, but maybe ben is still around: the Euler-Lagrange equation describes the minimizer of the action functional on a certain constrained function space. There is a related notion about minimization of an action in Freidlin-Wentzell theory, part of which is about SDEs with small noise.

Comment: (Cont.) In "sufficiently simple" situations, the likely paths between two points for an SDE with small noise are concentrated in a narrow tube around a certain deterministic path, which is analogous to the solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation. The action doesn't look quite the same, so it's not quite an Euler-Lagrange equation, but the spirit is the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what the OP means by extension to SDEs. The Euler-Lagrange equation is a pde that describes the first-order condition i.e. Frechet derivative for the Lagrangian $L$ inside a functional.

If you want a stochastic version of taking Frechet derivatives of functionals, then Malliavin calculus was developed to address this (in the context of reproving Hormander's theorem). See Nualart ["The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics"](https://The%20Malliavin%20Calculus%20and%20Related%20Topics).

If you have some optimal-control problem in mind, then indeed on can use large deviation tools such Freidlin-Wentzell theory. See ["A control version of the Freidlin-Wentzell Theorem"](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Epworah/wf.pdf).